# Angular 2 Write HTML table to existing Excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel, angular, xlsx

I have an Angular 2 app, in which I create a dynamic HTML table.
I want to insert this table into an existing Excel file, from a specific cell (for example W5 etc.).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you actually need a library that can produce excel files, try using https://github.com/jsegarra1971/MyExcel. No sure it can work with existing files.